# Getting JUST the onTouch event (Android)

Tags: android, ontouchlistener

I am trying to separate a few things in here.

I have a program with Imagebuttons. They have onTouchListeners attached to them.

I wish touch event to be fired JUST with a touch, not with a click. I mean, if I use a mouse to click, for example, I don't want the onTouch event attached to the ImageButton to be fired. However it IS fired when you click the mouse over the button.

Is it possible to fire the event JUST when a touch happens?

My code:

```
myImageButton.setOnTouchListener(new Button.OnTouchListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent arg1) {
                 if (arg1.getAction() == android.view.MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {    
                    Toast.makeText(LiVoiceActivity.this,
                                    "You touched me!",
                                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
                 return true;
            }
    });
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a field known as a Tool_Type in the MotionEvent class.  I have implemented a check for the mouse type here:

**API 14 AKA EASY MODE**

```
myImageButton.setOnTouchListener(new Button.OnTouchListener() {
                @Override
                public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent arg1) {
                     if (arg1.getAction() == android.view.MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN
                              && (MotionEvent.TOOL_TYPE_MOUSE != arg1.getToolType(0)) {    
                        Toast.makeText(LiVoiceActivity.this,
                                        "You touched me!",
                                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                     return true;
                }
        });
```

**API 9**

```
myImageButton.setOnTouchListener(new Button.OnTouchListener() {
                @Override
                public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent arg1) {
                     if (arg1.getAction() == android.view.MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN
                              && (arg1.getSize() > 1) {    
                        Toast.makeText(LiVoiceActivity.this,
                                        "You touched me!",
                                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                     return true;
                }
        });
```

Now this checks the size of the MotionEvent received.  PRESUMABLY, a mouse click would have a size of 1, therefore, only recognize sizes bigger than 1.  Play around with that number and see if you can differentiate between the mouse and finger touch.

Comment: jack57, thank you for your answer. I tried to use your code but it says TOOL_TYPE_MOUSE cannot be resolved also, it can't find the method getToolType(). Any tips?

Comment: Sounds like an API problem :( .  What API are you working with? Ex. API 10 == Android 2.3.3

Comment: Confirmed API issue, only works on 14 and above.  Please let me know what API you are working on.